# SDK for Developer

Tags: man, development, documentation, system-programming

Is there any SDK for developers under Linux? I mean more than man pages, it would be more like MSDN Library or Windows SDK under windows, where all documentation about programming and developer guide is documented and structured in one place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For GNOME, you can check out devhelp or [help.gnome.org](https://help.gnome.org/).

But as everyone has already stated, there is no single SDK for "Linux".  You need to have some idea of what you want before we can recommend specific developer resources.

Comment: so they (the system/lib/distro developer) is very good at making thousands of little piece to work together than to agree about how to standardize a document in order to make app developer create better apps faster. no wonder *nix apps are less compared to windows or even osx

Comment: @uray, there are a lot of different ways to program for GNU/Linux.  If you use comprehensive libraries like GNOME, KDE, or Qt, you may find that most of the documentation you need is in fact in one place.

Comment: @uray GNU/Linux is a living breathing environment going through a lot of changes. Writing it off as having a porely developed userland is very subjective. For most of it's history it has been the platform of power-users, people who spend most of their time in text, shunning the world of Desktop Environments and other hoo-ey. This has been changing lately as GNU/Linux gains wider exceptence/use. If you embrace the Unix side of linux, it is much more rich and well developed than OSX or Windows. If you're looking for shiny mouse-bait, you'll have to wait for it to catch up.

Answer (score 5):

A unified SDK implies a single source for all the core libraries.  That just isn't the way open source operating systems work.  Bits and pieces come from all over, and they're all separately documented.

**EDIT**: If paper's not a problem for you, the closest thing to what you're asking for is [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](http://www.apuebook.com/) 2/e by Stevens and Rago.

Comment: if that so, lets just take only for linux kernel for example, is there any structured documentation for kernel API instead of just list of man pages? is there any way we can search for a topic or follow a guide on a document of more like "developer guide"

Comment: Added recommendation paragraph for the Stevens book.

Answer (score 3):

MSDN only documents Microsoft technologies, and not other libraries or frameworks to use on Windows; it doesn't include documentation from other vendors.  Now, linux distros use software from much more organisations & companies, so the documentation also tends to be more distributed and less uniform.  (And sometimes documentation isn't done very well, unfortunately.)

Also, most linux distros come with a documentation browser that bundles the documentation from various sources in one place.

Many of the important parts of a linux distro *do* have nice documentation libraries BTW, e.g.:

- https://developer.gnome.org/
- http://docs.python.org/

Answer (score 0):

What I recommended if you're also interested in developing cross-platform applications is the [Nokia Qt SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/Tools/) which provides the [Qt framework](http://qt.nokia.com) and other tools, which from my experience has one of the best documentations available, see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/ and http://qt.nokia.com/developer

Some videos to watch: [this](http://www.youtube.com/qtstudios#p/u/23/p0xiKBEx8RA) and [this](http://www.youtube.com/user/ICSNetwork#p/u/19/ojZQFZoLTRU)

For understanding what Qt is and what you can do with it check out: http://qt.nokia.com/

Also Qt is the framework of choice to build apps for [MeeGo](http://www.meego.com) platform. (watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/user/ICSNetwork#p/u/0/TY-HHfYeukk))